# Q: How to share a url from ASP.NET website to facebook page of a user

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I've downloaded the nuget for Facebook and I'm missing the code I need to add to share info on a user's timeline.

Now I'm new to using facebook api so my question does include relatively basic stuff, I have FacebookClient object in with the SDK but I'm not sure how to use it.

I want to be able to share a url (with the most basic way, will research further on my own.)

If anyone has any ideas or has done it before, I don't want examples, just a simple explanation on how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use offline sharing you can use graph api:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/status

and you can use graph api explorer to test:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools-and-support/

If you want user to click share button and share via Share Dialog, you can use JS api:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

I prefer JS api in my projects.